# Vue + Firebase get all users with custom claim

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a custom claim "admin" attached to each user, carrying a boolean.
Now, in my frontend i am trying to generate a list of all admins.
For that i need to access all users who have said custom claim set to "true" and put them in an array, which i can then generate the list from.
The array should just look like the following:

```
const admins = ref([
    {
        uid: *uid of admin1*,
        name: *name of admin1*,
    },
    {
        uid: *uid of admin2*,
        name: *name of admin2*,
    },
    ...
])
```

So the following problems arise:

1. How do i access all users with said custom claim set to true, so that i can loop over them and populate my array?
2. Is this a case for a cloud function, so that it can not be manipulated?

I tried reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) Firebase documentation, however i could not make sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do i access all users with said custom claim set to true, so that i can loop over them and populate my array?

There is no direct way to query users based on custom claims.

> Is this a case for a cloud function?

Yes, you would have to list all users as in the documentation that you've shared and check for custom claims for each user separately.

---

It might be best to use a database like Firestore or Realtime Database and maintain a collection of all admins. Make sure this cannot be updated from client side directly using security rules.